# How to define multiple css pseudo class for one class?

Tags: css

.struct a:link, .struct a:visited {color:#5AB4F9;}

Is this a correct way of doing it? If not how? Thanx in advances.

Comment: Is this the correct way of doing _what_? Grouping selectors? Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Id depends on what you're trying to achieve:

That one will work for an element which is `:link` **OR** `:visited`:

```
.struct a:link, .struct a:visited {color:#5AB4F9;}
```

And that one with work for an element which is `:link` **AND** `:visited` at the same time:

```
.struct a:link:visited {color:#5AB4F9;}
```

Comment: I don't know why my question is confusing. It can't be anymore clearer. Is what I post the correct syntax for it? are there any other way to syntax for grouping selectors?